# sshd AllowGroups group not granting access

Tags: centos, sshd, openssh

I have this weird situation: On a Centos 6.6 box, in my `sshd_config`, I have the line

```
AllowGroups foo bar baz
```

just like on all the other servers.
However, when user `baz` (whose group is `baz`) tries to login on this one server, login is denied,

In the logs I see

```
May 17 16:27:03 myserver sshd[6172]: User baz from other.server.com not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups
```

And the user cannot login. Of course I have restarted the ssh daemon to make sure the config is picked up.

Also, if I completely remove the 'AllowGroups' line from the `sshd_config`, login works. Now I am wondering why sshd is not picking up
this group (also, users within the group bar can login with `AllowGroups` active).
Also, the (seemingly) exact setup works on other hosts. The configuration is deployed via puppet, so it really should be identical.
Any ideas?

**Edit** as requested below, the output of

```
root@foobar:/etc/ssh $ groups baz
baz : nburoot
```

exepcted would be `baz` as group ... so now I need to check why the group is wrong (even though `/etc/groups` has it right). I will post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Maybe the `AllowGroups` is in a `Match` section of `sshd_cofig` ?

Comment: Please, post whole `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with context that is needed. Also post the output of `groups baz` to make sure the groups are correct.

Comment: It might also be helpful to know if these are local groups (i.e. defined in /etc/group) or from a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jakuje I checked the group membership with `groups baz` which showed that the effective group is not what I expecting from the entry in `/etc/group`. As we also have centrify installed, I looked at the config, which seems correct(`baz` was listed in `/etc/centrifydc/groups.ignore`). I restarted the agent (`service centrifydc restart`), which fixed the issue. `baz` now has the correct group and can therefor login.